# TSQL Select where one column equals another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm trying to create a search based on where items go together in the same table.

So if I input a value like `a123` for column `BoxNo` then all values in the column `Goeswith` which are also `a123` are selected. This below code is my attempt, but does not work.

```
SELECT *   
FROM Equipment 
WHERE (BoxNo LIKE '%') = GoesWith
```

thanks

Comment: `SELECT * From Equipment WHERE BoxNo = GoesWith`.

Comment: your question is confusing, can you give sample records with desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   'a123' IN (BoxNo, GoesWith)
```

or maybe this,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   BoxNo LIKE '%a123%' AND
        BoxNo = GoesWith
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want all rows where BoxNo and GoesWith have the same value then it's this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Equipment
WHERE BoxNo = GoesWith
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search all items like `a123` in `BoxNo` column:

```
SELECT * From Equipment WHERE BoxNo LIKE '%a123%'
```

Of if you want to search for `a123` in both columns:

```
DECLARE @Search Varchar(50) = 'a123'
SELECT * From Equipment WHERE BoxNo = @Search AND GoesWith = @Search
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you meant 'as well as', hence OR:

select * from equipment where BoxNo='a123' OR GoesWith='a123'

Be a bit careful to add bracketing if you need some further constraints adding...

Answer (score 1):

Were you looking for a general match of all Box records that have another entry that they "go with"?
if so then you need an self-join (which uses aliases to identify the records):

```
select
  b.BoxNo,
  g.GoesWith
from
     equipment as b
inner join equipment as g on b.BoxNo = g.GoesWith
```

This identifies all the records that have a matching box (and which thing they go with). 
Change to a left join to include records that have no match.
It will produce multiple matches if a Box has several GoesWith entries, but by returning either DISTINCT b.* or DISTINCT g.* you can get a list of individual matches.